# NPE when injecting the same service in parent and child class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

The project uses Hybris, so our business logic is built upon OOTB read-only classes.
[image: diagram]

The issue is that in one readonly class, one of the injected services is private, with no getter method.
We extended this class to our custom class, where we happen to need the same service.

Hybris bean definitions:

```
<alias name="defaultCatalogService" alias="catalogService"/>
<bean id="defaultCatalogService" class="de.hybris.platform.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogService"
      parent="abstractBusinessService">
    <property name="catalogVersionService" ref="catalogVersionService"/>
</bean>
```

Custom bean def:

```
<alias name="customCategoryService" alias="categoryService"/>
<bean id="customCategoryService" class="core.services.category.customCategoryServiceImpl"
      parent="defaultCategoryService">
    <property name="catalogVersionService" ref="catalogVersionService"/>
</bean>
```

The NPE comes when we call a child method, in which we attempt to call the parent's method. When this happens the parent's service is null.
During build both setters get called.

I've tried removing the property from the child class and beans-xml, and also commenting out the methods which were depending on it.
By doing this the parent class didn't get null for the injected service and the call ran without any issue.

Right now I don't have any clue where the null may come from.
I wonder if for some reason Spring can't wire the same bean twice.

Edit:
The NPE is thrown when we try to call getSessionCatalogVersions() on the injected null service.

```java
private CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService;

...

@Required
public void setCatalogVersionService(final CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService)
{
    this.catalogVersionService = catalogVersionService;
}    
    
...

private String getCatalogVersionsString()
{
    return CatalogUtils.getCatalogVersionsString(catalogVersionService.getSessionCatalogVersions());
}
```

Comment: Please show at least the bean definitions as code, not as screenshot.

Comment: *I wonder if for some reason Spring can't wire the same bean twice.* No reason, especially you can even autowire A into A.

Comment: Share actual code. Maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: You override the setter in one and the other one is effectivly useless, hence the parent one is `null`. You need to call `super.setYourProperty` from your overridden method else the parent one will remain `null` .

Comment: Thank you! Could you move your comment to the answers, so I can accept it?